# How do you check if a storagefolder is null c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm surprised this has not come up before and im thinking im just not using the right search terms but been stuck on this for an hour now.

heres the issue, when some one presses the roll button on my app i want a folder picker to appear and allow the person to pick a folder, then the files are saved in that folder. I only want it to run once.

heres what i have

```
FolderPicker folder =new FolderPicker();
folder.FileTypeFilter.Add(".html");
folder.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
folder.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
folder.SettingsIdentifier = "folder";
theFolder = await folder.PickSingleFolderAsync(); 
StorageFile file = await theFolder.CreateFileAsync(name + ".html",  CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

this works but ofcourse the picker appears every time i run the method (as its setup to do at the moment.

StorageFolder theFolder set up at the start of the programs run simply as 
    public StorageFolder theFolder;

i have tried changing

```
theFolder = await folder.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

to

```
while (theFolder.Equals(null))
{
    theFolder = await folder.PickSingleFolderAsync(); 
}
```

but that just causes a crash

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an Object."
```

i also tried getting the display name of the folder and if it was blank then getting the folderpicker to show...same error

I can not even just have the folder picker show every time the person clicks run as a click of cancel will crash it (and it would be very annoying to the user)

any ideas ?

my app is a universal app in c# for windows phone and store, it is the windows store version im currently working on

Comment: have you tried a google search [msdn FolderPicker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207881?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: i had read all i could find on it, most of the msdn examples deal with files rather then folders. But the solution has been found (i just cant accept it as an answer yet due to low reputation (some people here do not like newbie coders)

Comment: keep in mind that there is a difference between 
`==` and `theFolder.Equals` once deals with value comparison and the .Equals deals with Object equality comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If variable is null you can't call method on it.

```
while (theFolder == null)
{
    theFolder = await folder.PickSingleFolderAsync(); 
}
```

Comment: works on the windows app, however on the phone PickSingleFolderAsync has been removed and you need to use PickFolderAndContinue()
only thats a void method so on the phone im back to square one how are you ment to get a storage folder from the picker now !